# Altium Symbol Wizard only in imperial

Tags: altium, units

We have now got Altium 17 installed and set up, and I've used it to make various schematics.

One feature of the software is the Symbol Wizard for creating our own symbols for different components. It's great for labelling up the component pins and so on. However, when I make the component, it is all aligned on an imperial gird, despite all of the pages being set to metric.

This isn't noticeable until I try and use it in a schematic, and none of my metric wires can match up to the imperially aligned pins.

Is there a setting for units for the symbol wizard?

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: Don't use metric for schematics. Use the supplied DXP units whereas 1DXP unit = 10mil.
You will encounter lots of problems when using metric symbols.

We're using metric for the PCB and about everything else, but imperial for the schematic.

Do yourself a favor, don't use metric for the schematic.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems like advice based on experience.

Comment: It is, it's also based on various threads in the Altium forum. This, and don't try to use a different font than the default in the schematic. You're wasting your time in the end (as sad as this might be).

Comment: This is my experience as well using metric symbols.  It's a disaster on the schematic sheet.  I get all kinds of off-grid errors and my schematics just don't align well.  Next time I do a new schematic, I'll make sure to start with imperial.